# jquery remove class after css animation played?

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation, webkit

I have the css code:

```
body.start{-webkit-animation:srcb ease-in .4s 1;}
```

and just play once when entered the website

but the problem is while the animation done

the buttons in my site isn't works

how can I remove the body class "start" after animation done

or remove class delay x seconds after animation played?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can bind to the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) event (to all of them, actually):

```
$("body").on(
    "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd",
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("start");
    }
);
```

If you want to implement a delay, you can [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) the class removal operation:

```
$("body").on(
    "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd",
    function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).queue(function() {  // Wait for 1 second.
            $(this).removeClass("start").dequeue();
        });
    }
);
```

*Note:* [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) only exists since jQuery 1.7, if you are using an older release you will have to use [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead for the code above to work.

Comment: @jkjk, can you elaborate on how this is not working? Does the handler run at all on your browser? Did you put the code in a `ready` handler or in a `<script>` element located at the bottom of your page?

Comment: The answer from @zeno2k using AnimationEnd not only worked for me but is more aligned with the question in my opinion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702258/810794

Comment: Note: [Most modern browsers now support the un-prefixed event](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend
```

instead of

```
transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This answer is more like a comment for accepted answer. Please explain how to use these properties so that the answer can stand on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Another way perhaps?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body.start').removeClass('start')
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: This works, but in theory it's a lot more brittle. If you need to remove the class immediately after (e.g. if you're animating on click) this isn't as good as listening for the animationEnd event.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');

function callback() {
    div.classList.remove('start'); // or modify div.className
}

div.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callback, false);
```

Check this [live example](http://jsbin.com/omujos/3/edit) on jsbin.

Please notice, that your animation and my solution work only in webkit-based browsers. In production environment you should take into consideration other browsers **and** mandatory provide prefix-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to always remove the animation class at the start of the event listener, run some small code in-between and then add the animation class again and it worked. It will now always trigger the animation. In my case I wanted a wobble animation to be triggered if the password was wrong. Not sure of your reasoning. I wanted the animation removed so the animation would always trigger again, even if they repeatedly hit submit and it was wrong.

```
$j('#submitLogin').on('click',function(){    
    if(true){
       //login
    }else{
       $j('.lockIcon').removeClass('wobble-hor-top');
       $j(this).prev().prev().addClass('invalid');
       $j('.loadIconKey').hide();
       $j('.lockIcon').addClass('wobble-hor-top');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the top two comments, but I also needed to add a callback to the event to get mine working

```
$("body").on( 
    "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
    function(e) {
        $(e.target).removeClass("animation-css-rule");
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass("start",
    function() {
        alert("do something");
    });
```